# tengo un json y lo quiero insertar en dynamodb y no entiendo como hacer la insersion

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dynamodb

este es el json que tengo con el objeto "item" que quiero insertar en dynamodb

```
{{
  "Codigo": "ABR1100",
  "Marca": "ABRAZADERAS PLASTICAS dolarizado",
  "Descripcion": "ABRAZADERA PLAST 100 X 2,5 MM NEGRO",
  "Precio": 0.714,
  "Descuentos": "-40%",
  "Iva": "21%",
  "Proveedor": "40139e76-218a-4bcb-9c39-5af13e4d9fa4",
  "FechaActualizacionPrecio": "25/3/2019",
  "Id": "6ff3dea1-2a88-fb97-8b4e-2788cc45c9d6",
  "update": false,
  "TimeStamp": "20190325063143358",
  "HashKey": "Articulos#79f4ab50-bcd3-4c49-a54d-c329dac9bbb3",
  "SortKey": "6ff3dea1-2a88-fb97-8b4e-2788cc45c9d6#20190325063143358",
  "HashKey_index_1": "Articulos#79f4ab50-bcd3-4c49-a54d-c329dac9bbb3#6ff3dea1-2a88-fb97-8b4e-2788cc45c9d6",
  "SortKey_index_1": "20190325063143358",
  "Estado": "AC",
  "TipoDato": "Articulos",
  "CompetenciaCreadora": "79f4ab50-bcd3-4c49-a54d-c329dac9bbb3",
  "CompetenciaPropietaria": "79f4ab50-bcd3-4c49-a54d-c329dac9bbb3",
  "iidd": 1
}}
```

y directamente hago esto:

```
table.PutItem(item);
```

el error que me tira es el siguiente:

> error: La mejor coincidencia de método sobrecargado para
>   'Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel.Table.PutItem(Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel.Document,
>   Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel.PutItemOperationConfig)' tiene algunos
>   argumentos no válidos
>   Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: La mejor
>   coincidencia de método sobrecargado para
>   'Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel.Table.PutItem(Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel.Document,
>   Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel.PutItemOperationConfig)' tiene algunos
>   argumentos no válidos    en CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Table
>   , Object )    en
>   System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid2[T0,T1](CallSite
>   site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)

Comment: `error: La mejor coincidencia de método sobrecargado para` con esta primera linea, se puede decir que esta llamadando a la sobrecarga equivocada o le estas pasando como parametro un tipo que no es. Si prestas atencion al error que colcaste veras cuales son los parametros a pasar. Por cierto ese json que colocaste no tiene el formato correcto.